# C array: showing big numbers as the output when its index goes out of bound

Tags: c, arrays

I was trying to test what output I would get when I tried to print the array that the index goes out of bound.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{

    int arr[] = { 3, 4, 5 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == 0)
        {
            printf("Breaking out of the loop.");
            break;

        }

        else
            printf("%i\n", arr[i]);
    }


    getchar();
}
```

When I run this code, the output is:

```
3
4
5
-858993460
3997200
```

I expected it to print out "Breaking out of the loop" and break out of the loop and terminate.
I truly have no idea how it even printed those numbers.

Any idea what those numbers mean?

P.S. I am sorry if this is a stupid question, I am quite new to C.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: How do you expect to print "Breaking out of loop"? Your code never hits that condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory out of bounds of an array, or dynamically allocated memory, doesn't belong to you, and its content is indeterminate. Accessing arrays or memory out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Just don't do it.